# XSLT: repeat one node with each sequential node

Tags: xslt, repeat

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
    <div>
        <div class="theheader">The first header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thecontent">
        <div class="col1">Col 1 </div>
        <div class="col2">Col 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thecontent">
        <div class="col1">Col 3 </div>
        <div class="col2">col 4 </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="theheader">The second header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thecontent">
        <div class="col1">Col 5 </div>
        <div class="col2">Col 6 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thecontent">
        <div class="col1">Col 7 </div>
        <div class="col2">Col 8 </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

This is the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='theheader']" />

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='thecontent']">
        <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='theheader']" /><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
The first header: Col 1 Col 2
The first header: Col 3 col 4
The first header: Col 5 Col 6
The first header: Col 7 Col 8
```

Desired output:

```
The first header: Col 1 Col 2
The first header: Col 3 col 4
The second header: Col 5 Col 6
The second header: Col 7 Col 8
```

How can it be done? XSLT 1.0 preferred.

Also tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//div[@class='theheader']" /><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
```

(the dot before //) and no header is output. Can anyone tell me why?
Edited the examples because first edition was too simplified. Now SO tells me it's too much code. Hope this surplus text helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to move the code to output the header from the template matching "theheader" into the template matching "thecontent" instead, so that it is repeated. You will also need to make use of the `preceding-sibling` axis to get the div you need.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='theheader']" />

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='thecontent']">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::div[div/@class='theheader'][1]/div" /><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="div">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to your comment about the `theheader` potentially being more levels deep, try one of these expressions instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::div[descendant::div/@class='theheader'][1]//div[@class='theheader']" />

<xsl:value-of select="preceding::div[@class='theheader'][1]" />
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but I was oversimplifying my example. Now rewritten. Hope you can look at the new edition.

Comment: @Peter: How do you want the XSLT to behave if there are headers but no content?  Just checking your requirements for edge cases...

Comment: Nice observation John. Content is guaranteed.

Comment: @Peter - I have amended my answer to cope with this situation

Comment: @Tim: working perfectly. Thanks again. But, I am still simplifying. The header node is deep buried and the level can change. All I know is that each header (theheader) is present before each content (thecontent)

Comment: @Peter: I've made an edit to my post to show a couple of alternative expressions you could use.

Comment: @Tim: Those look really promising. Here it's time for dinner. I'll try your suggestions tomorrow and post back. Thank you!

Comment: preceding:: together with the [1] made it work in my original html. Really learned a lot here.